# python function type mismatch

Tags: python, function, types, arguments

I have defined the function as followed:

```
 def pick(l: list, index: int) -> int:
   return l[index]
```

It means then I must pass the integer parameter as the second argument.
but when I use,

```
print(pick(['a', 'b', 'c'],True)) #returns me the 'b'.
```

The reason why I've moved from PHP to PYTHON is that PHP was a headache for me. (I mean not strongly typed variables, and also work with utf-8 strings).

How to restrict the passing boolean argument as an integer?

Comment: Python is not strongly typed either. You can check for the type inside the function and raise an error if it's the wrong type.

Comment: typically typing and a type checker configured on IDE should be enough, but if you want your code to reject that at runtime, you can use the following: `if not isinstance(index, int): raise TypeError`

Comment: @matszwecja Please type it as an answer and I will mark it as useful

Comment: @LeoGarsia Answered with some additional info because my comment might have been slightly incorrect.

Comment: @matszwecja  I think that typing in python is formal. Since instead of an integer, the function returned a string without restriction. There is no need to declare types of variables.

Comment: @LeoGarsia Correct, typing is just a formality, and it has absolutely no bearing on code execution. But it exists so you can configure your IDE to do type checking based on those hints and *warn* you that you are passing/returning type different than specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually typing and a type checker configured on IDE should be enough. If you want to enforce typechecking at runtime, you can use the following:

```
if not isinstance(index, int):
    raise TypeError
```

In Python though, `bool` is a subclass of `int` - `isinstance(False, int)` returns `True`. Which means TypeError will still not be raised. You could use

```
if isinstance(index, bool):
    raise TypeError
```

but at that point I don't really see much reason to do so if programmer really wants to use such a construct - especially since based on language specification `bool` is an `int`, so should be accepted wherever `int` is - [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)